# Deploying Rails 6 app using Docker and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx

As I deploy my first ever rails app to server, I keep getting this error right when from home url.

> **The page you were looking for doesn't exist.** You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

My configuration:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.0.0-alpine3.13
RUN apk add --no-cache --no-cache --update alpine-sdk nodejs postgresql-dev yarn tzdata
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .
RUN bundle install
COPY . .

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 4000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-e", "production", "-p", "4000"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
central:
    build:
      context: ./central
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 4000 -e production -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - ./central:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
      - ./central/.env.prod
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - centraldb
  centraldb:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - centraldb:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./central/.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/prod/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./central/public/:/home/apps/central/public/:ro
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - central
    links:
      - central
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: '/bin/sh -c ''while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g "daemon off;"'''
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream theapp {
    server central:4000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name thedomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name thedomain.com;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    # hidden ssl config

    root   /home/apps/central/public;
    index  index.html;

    location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {    
        try_files $uri @rails;     
        access_log off;    
        gzip_static on; 
        # to serve pre-gzipped version     
        expires max;    
        add_header Cache-Control public;     

        add_header Last-Modified "";    
        add_header ETag "";    
        break;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rails;
    }

    location @rails {
        proxy_pass http://theapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /home/apps/central/public;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/central_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/central_access.log;
}
```

As I check the log file of nginx but it doesn't show anything.
The app work well in my local and even in production with ports config (of course if I go to `thedomain.com:4000`), but I need to serve it with Nginx in production with `thedomain.com` so I need solution for this.

Comment: What's the actual URL you're connecting to?  Do you get a corresponding entry in the `central_access.log` file?

Comment: I do have corresponding entry to access log:
It's like this: 
la/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"